# Whats the scope of tag wikis?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

In the help docs it just says

> Community wiki posts have been donated to the community in hopes that
>   others will edit them to keep them up to date, to add useful
>   information, and generally improve their quality.

When editing to improve a tag wiki what is the recommended scope?  What information should be included to create what would be considered a high quality, complete tag wiki?

I've edited several tag wiki's and while browsing through them have found a variety of styles..

1. A full length wiki with information on the subjects background, origin, history, etc.. (e.g. encyclopedic.. Wikipedia style)
2. Only information that people may find useful in answering questions.. common questions and their answers & reference information.
3. Only information that would educate on how to intelligently discuss the subject or present  question regarding the subject.

I enjoy writing about a subject.  It helps me learn.  So I am tempted to go on and on and expand on every aspect of a subject if I start writing.  But too much information could be bloat and make it difficult to be useful if people are only referencing them for answers rather than a broader education of the subject.

Comment: Why are you quoting from the [Edit Community Wiki privilege page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki)? (There does seem to be a dearth of information about writing good tag wikis, however. When editing a tag wiki the sidebar contains a link to [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/).)

Comment: Community Wiki and Tag wikis are not the same thing. To what are you referring?